# mysql query with Order by descrese performance

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, query-performance

I have a query which has 7-8 table join, and major 4 tables has approximately 200000 records. this query needs conditional order by clause as per result. this query returns results in 1.6 seconds. I think this is very slow, I expect result should be come within 200ms. So I have checked execution plan using EXPLAIN command, and it's shows me in first line that 49150 rows scanned Using where; Using temporary and Using filesort.

Now I have put this query as subquery (like "SELECT * FROM ( My Actual Query ) a ORDER BY a.field ) and then check with EXPLAIN command. so this time it shows me 5454396 rows scanned using filesort. and my result come within 1 second. I don't understand which is better way to achive performance, because this plan scanned much more rows compare to first query plan.

If first query is right for me, then how do I avoid "Using temporary" and keep order by as I needed?

EDIT :

I have updated my schema and query with execution plan [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60745/mysql-query-with-order-by-descrese-performance)

Comment: Please post your schema and the queries.

Comment: @Barmar, It is hard to post schema and query here, But as I said earlier, my second query plan shows many rows compare to first query plan and removes "Using where; Using temporary" in second plan. Is it ok or not?

Comment: It's easy to post schema and query here. Paste the `CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT` queries into the question, mark them with the mouse, and use the `{}` tool to mark them as code so they'll be formatted properly. Make sure you use only spaces for indentations, not tabs.

Comment: @Barmar, :) It is not allowed to share at my office.

Comment: I don't know how you expect anyone to answer the question then. Query planning is very dependent on the structure of the data and the contents of the tables.

Comment: sorry @Barmar, but I can't break my company's low. But I shared some figures of query plan, It is ok as your opinion, means I feel that scanned records is bed for performance, here in my case its perform well for me.

Comment: it doesn't have to be real data, you just have to provide something that demonstrates the problem. How can we suggest changes to a query if there's no query to work with?

Comment: @Barmar, I have posted schema and query here : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60745/mysql-query-with-order-by-descrese-performance. this can help you